# Export variable from componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs

How do I export the "x" variable from componentDidMount so i can use it in the render section? I am trying to check for the x position of my div.

```
import React from 'react';

class Icon extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.selector = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    var rect = this.selector.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    var x = rect.top;
    console.log(x);
   };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="icon" ref={this.selector}>
        <p>x: {x} & y:</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Icon;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not to use the state?

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   state = {
      x: null,
   };

   this.selector = React.createRef();
}
```

then inside lifecycle:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
   var rect = this.selector.current.getBoundingClientRect();
   this.setState({ x: rect.top });
};
```

and finally inside render:

```
<p>x: {this.state.x} & y:</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

As they said before, most of the time you want to track the state of the data being drawn, and if the state changes, let react to automatically draw the data change

but if you don't want to track state for any reason, you can use an attribute, instead of using `x`, use `this.x`

```
import React from 'react';

class Icon extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.selector = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    var rect = this.selector.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    this.x = rect.top;
    console.log(this.x);
   };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="icon" ref={this.selector}>
        <p>x: {this.x} & y:</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Icon;
```